# Query sObject with different type

Tags: soql, governorlimits

I need to do a query in the database, the idea is to retrieve at the same time all the object id's and do it in a way you don't touch the limits.

Something like:

```
[Select Id from sObject Where Id > :lastCallMaxId Limit 100 Order by Id];
```

Is it possible? since I can insert many different sObjects at the same time but I can not query them together sObject.

```
insert new List<sObject>{new Account(name = 'Account Name'), new Contact(lastName = 'Last Name')};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need at least one query per unrelated object. I've suggested [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLtAAI) to make Apex Code a bit more functional. For now, you will need to find a way to stay within the SOQL limit without being able to combine calls.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have SOQL query which returns multiple object records. But multiple object records can be retrived in a single query using SOSL.
for ex: FIND {test} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account, Contact, Lead, Opportunity

Comment: I have tried, but since  I have to set the limit and offset it is not working in this case

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it seems to me you are asking how to get back the Id of a record already inserted within the transaction. No re-query is required. The Id is populated in memory.

```
List<SObject> records = new List<SObject>{
    new Account(/*data*/),
    new Contact(/*data*/)
    // etc.
};
insert records; 

Id accountId = records[0].Id;
Id contactId = records[1].Id;
```

Comment: It is just an example, what I am looking for is the way to select them together, the "inverse" to the example you say.